# Computer game datasets

Tags: data-mining, dataset

I have been looking for computer game datasets, but so far I've only been able to find the 'Avatar History' dataset for WoW.

Are there any other interesting datasets out there, possibly for other genres?

Comment: this should be community wiki.

Answer (score 7):

**Starcraft I**

- [Starcraft Data Mining Project](http://eis.ucsc.edu/StarCraft_Data_Mining), providing some game data.
- [Starcraft AI Competition](http://eis.ucsc.edu/StarCraftAICompetition), does not directly provide data, but allows you to connect a program written by you with the game. Although I did not try it, I expect that data collection is possible this way ;).

If you are generally interested in data mining + gaming, you may find the project [Robocode aka Java Robot Wars](http://robocode.sourceforge.net/) interesting, where you can program a bot for a simpler environment (simpler than Starcraft) and let it battle against other bots.

Answer (score 1):

- John Myles White has a [dataset and analysis of Canabalt scores as posted on Twitter](http://www.johnmyleswhite.com/notebook/2009/11/15/the-top-scores-for-canabalt-take-2/)
- Stats at Berkeley has a dataset for a [Video Games Survey](http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/users/statlabs/labs.html#video).